# Xamarin.Forms UWP - Can't update view within ViewCell (works in iOS)

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms MVVM mobile app, with a page that has a `ListView`.

I'm trying to access one of the `ViewCell`'s in the `ListView`, and then update content inside that `ViewCell` right after the page loads. Ultimately, I'm trying to animate (via `TranslateTo()`), but for testing purposes, I'm just trying to make something within the `ViewCell` invisible (by setting `IsVisible = false`).

It works on my iOS project, but not on my UWP one. Nothing happens; the `ViewCell` content is never affected.

The basic code is:

```
----------------
MyPage.cs
----------------
public MyPage() // constructor
{
    _viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    ...
    ...
}

// on page load, subscribe to a message that modifies a ViewCell in the ListView;
// when that message is called in the ViewModel, it correctly modifies the ViewCell
// in iOS, but in UWP it does nothing;
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyViewModel>(this, "ModifyViewCell", (sender) =>
    {
        // get item cell to modify (for testing, just get first one);
        // see code in ListViewExt.cs a little farther down for GetCell() method
        MyViewCellView viewCell = GetCell(0); // MyViewCellView : ViewCell

        // modify cell - try different methods
        viewCell.IsEnabled = false;
        viewCell.View.IsVisible = false;
        viewCell.MyViewInsideCell.IsVisible = false; // <<<==== breakpoint
    }
}


-------------------
MyViewModel.cs
-------------------
public MyViewModel() // constructor
{
    // send message to update ViewCell in ListView
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "ModifyViewCell");
    });
}
```

`ViewCell`s of a `ListView` are stored in a Dictionary in a custom `ListView` class (`ListViewExt`) when the `ListView.SetupContent()` method is called (overridden below):

```
ListViewExt.cs
------------------------
// store ListView ViewCell's in dictionary for access later
public Dictionary<int, ViewCell> CellDict { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, ViewCell>();

protected override void SetupContent(Cell cell, int index)
{
    base.SetupContent(cell, index);

    // add ViewCell to dictionary on SetupContent()
    CellDict.Add(index, (ViewCell)cell);
}

public GetCell(int index)
{
    return CellDict[index];
}
```

I've also tried setting a breakpoint in the code on the line where I'm trying to modify the `ViewCell` (I've noted the breakpoint in a comment in the code above), and when I hover over `viewCell` at that point, Intellisense seems to indicate I have a valid reference to the `ViewCell` view (the `viewCell.MyViewInsideCell` - it says it's a Xamarin.Forms.Grid, which it is). But even with a valid reference, I can't seem to affect any of it's properties.

Is this a Xamarin UWP bug? It appears to be.

I've logged a [bug in Bugzilla here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60604).

[Here's a link to a sample project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TptFK0O1hICRofB3QHHvwr-ZZGRxRasU) where the issue is reproduced.

Comment: Could you show more detail about the Cell `BindingContext` or share a sample simple to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I've added a link to my sample project where the issue can be reproduced, and also included a link to the Bugzilla bug that I logged.